# AngularJS: make directive scope and controller scope variable in sync

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have created two directives(dirA, dirB). directiveA created scope variable not working in directiveB nor in controller scope.

//DirectiveA

```
myApp.directive("directiveA", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        replace: true,
        controller: 'myController',
        scope: {
            aData: "=aData",              //input to the directive
            cardData: "=cardData"      //input to the directive
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attr) {
             // some other code
        },
        templateUrl: 'directiveA.html'
    };
});
```

//DirectiveB

```
myApp.directive("directiveB", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        replace: true,
        controller: 'myController',
        scope: {
            bData: "=bData",                   //input to the directive
            cardData: "=cardData"           //input to the directive
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attr) {
                 // some other code
        },
        templateUrl: 'directiveB.html'
    };
});
```

//directiveA.html

```
<div>
    <span>Head A</span>

<input type="range" name="work_one" min='0' max=5' step="1" data-ng-init="selectedA=0" data-ng-model="selectedA" data-ng -     change="getSupportBList(aData[selectedA]);" value="0" />
        {{supportBList}}                      //Getting Proper result as expected.
</div>
```

//myController.js

```
//........
$scope.getSupportBList= function(val) {
    $scope.supportBList= ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'];
};
//........
```

//directiveB.html

```
<div>
    <div class="cardlabel">PortType</div>
    <div class="radio">
        <!-- portListData provided to directive as attribute -->
        <label class="radio-inline" data-ng-repeat="port in portListData">

            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="{{ port }}" data-ng-model="cardData" />{{ port }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I am using the same  `{{supportBList}}` in my controller view or in the directiveB.html template it is not returning any value. After inspecting with ng-inspector, the directiveA only have the  "supportBList" values. now, how can I make the "supportBList" available in the controller view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out a single quote for **directiveB** `templateUrl`

```
 templateUrl: directiveB.html'
```

should be changed to

```
 templateUrl: 'directiveB.html'
```

Comment: No, Actually there is no syntax error, while posting here there was a typo mistake.

Comment: @Suresh can you show me the `directiveB.html` content

Comment: Updated the question with directiveB.html

Comment: see I have created a jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/46oxqdzz/, now tell me what exactly you want, I can help you

Comment: Thank you Nidhish, on change on the range slider in directive A, will update the $scope.supportBList in controller. I want to get the updated supportBList in the directiveB. I am parsing these updated values as attribute to the directive B from the view inside that controller like <directive-b b-data="supportBList "></directive-b>. This supportBList array does not have any values in controller scope where as it has the values in directiveA scope.

Comment: Please find the exact issue in the jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/sureshvk/tb3kLtvx/4/

Comment: I solved this issue by using a parent controller and emit concept . thaks for your help.